# Need help with "is fond of when"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this a correct sentence ?  "She is fond of when her cat plays with her scarf", if not why ?
Thanks

Comment: What are your theories, pro and con?

Comment: Bcoz if the word **when** it's not correct.

Comment: "She likes it when [something happens]" is idiomatic, but "She is fond of when" sounds very odd. _Fond of_ has people or things as object.